# A thread-safe priority queue keeping its elements unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

This class is intended to be used in situations where [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) does not suffice, because the following two properties are needed.

- Every item in the queue can have a priority assigned.
- No item can occur more than once in the queue.

So here is my current implementation. I would be happy to hear your ideas on how the code can be improved.

```
"""A thread-safe priority queue keeping its elements unique
"""

import collections
import threading
import time
import unittest
from typing import DefaultDict, Deque, Set, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class OrderedSetPriorityQueue(Generic[T]):
    """A thread-safe priority queue keeping its elements unique"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.deques: DefaultDict[int, Deque[T]] = \
            collections.defaultdict(collections.deque)
        self.elem_sets: DefaultDict[int, Set[T]] = \
            collections.defaultdict(set)
        self.condition_var = threading.Condition(threading.RLock())

    def contains(self, item: T) -> bool:
        """Check if the item is already queued."""
        with self.condition_var:
            for elem_set in self.elem_sets.values():
                if item in elem_set:
                    return True
            return False

    def contains_with_prio(self, item: T, priority: int) -> bool:
        """Check if the item is already queued with this exact priority."""
        with self.condition_var:
            if priority not in self.elem_sets:
                return False
            return item in self.elem_sets[priority]

    def remove(self, item: T) -> bool:
        """Remove an item from the queue, disregarding its stored priority."""
        with self.condition_var:
            if not self.contains(item):
                return False
            removed_count = 0
            for set_prio, elem_set in self.elem_sets.items():
                if item in elem_set:
                    self.deques[set_prio].remove(item)
                    elem_set.remove(item)
                    removed_count += 1
            assert removed_count in [0, 1]
            self._clean_up()
            return removed_count > 0

    def put(self, item: T, priority: int = 0) -> bool:
        """Returns False if item already is queued with the same priority.
        If is has not been queued yet, it is added and True is returned.
        If it already was queued but with a different priority,
        the entry with the old priority will be removed,
        and the new one is added."""
        with self.condition_var:
            if self.contains_with_prio(item, priority):
                return False
            if self.contains(item):
                self.remove(item)
            self.deques[priority].appendleft(item)
            self.elem_sets[priority].add(item)
            self.condition_var.notify()
            return True

    def empty(self) -> bool:
        """Return True if the queue is completely empty."""
        with self.condition_var:
            assert bool(self.elem_sets) == bool(self.deques)
            return not self.elem_sets

    def size(self) -> int:
        """Number of elements in the queue."""
        with self.condition_var:
            return sum(map(len, self.elem_sets.values()))

    def get(self) -> T:
        """Pop the oldest item from the highest priority."""
        with self.condition_var:
            while not self.elem_sets:
                self.condition_var.wait()
            priority = sorted(self.deques.keys())[-1]
            item = self.deques[priority].pop()
            self.elem_sets[priority].remove(item)
            self._clean_up()
            return item

    def _clean_up(self) -> None:
        """Internal function used to clean up unused data structures."""
        with self.condition_var:
            assert sorted(self.deques.keys()) == sorted(self.elem_sets.keys())
            priorities = list(self.elem_sets.keys())
            for priority in priorities:
                if not self.deques[priority]:
                    del self.deques[priority]
                if not self.elem_sets[priority]:
                    del self.elem_sets[priority]


class OrderedSetPriorityQueueTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Verify integrity of custom queue implementation
    """

    def test_get_and_put(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0)
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_order(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0)
        queue.put(2)
        queue.put(1)
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(2, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(1, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_priority(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0, 0)
        queue.put(1, 1)
        self.assertEqual(1, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_increase_priority(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0, 0)
        queue.put(1, 1)
        queue.put(0, 2)
        self.assertEqual(2, queue.size())
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(1, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_decrease_priority(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0, 1)
        queue.put(1, 1)
        queue.put(0, 0)
        self.assertEqual(1, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_uniqueness(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()
        queue.put(0)
        queue.put(0)
        queue.put(1)
        queue.put(0)
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        self.assertEqual(1, queue.get())
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())

    def test_get_with_wait(self) -> None:
        queue: OrderedSetPriorityQueue[int] = OrderedSetPriorityQueue()

        def add_to_queue() -> None:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            queue.put(0)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=add_to_queue, args=(), kwargs={})
        thread.start()
        self.assertEqual(0, queue.get())
        thread.join()
        self.assertTrue(queue.empty())
```

Comment: You're aware of the `PriorityQueue` yes? (`from queue import PriorityQueue`) As for the constraint of no duplicate items, I guess you'll want to have a wrapper function to perform a check/comparison before actually adding data items to the priorityqueue.

Comment: @C.Harley Yes, I know `PriorityQueue`. But how can one check if an item is already present in it?

Comment: You'll want to create a wrapper function to perform a check/comparison **before** actually adding data items to the priorityqueue

Comment: Ah, so you mean maintaining additional sets for those checks like `self.elem_sets` in the current implementation. `put` would check if the item is already in the set before adding it to the wrapped queue. And `get` would remove the just-popped item from the set. Yes, seems to make sense. But I'm not yet sure how updating the priority of an item already in the queue would work.

Comment: If you're modifying items after they've been set, then your implementation is incorrectly assigning priority to begin with. Return to the drawing board and correct your design.

Comment: I'm not modifying the actual items, just replacing items of low priority with items of high priority. In my use-case the producer may get new information that makes it put `A, 2` some time after it already had put `A, 1` into the queue. In the case that `A, 1` has not yet been processed by the consumers, `A, 2` will be processed before `A, 1`anyways (due to the priority). And then having `A, 1` still in the queue does not make sense any more. It would just waste consumer capacity, since the operation they perform is idempotent. This is why I want to remove `A, 1`once `A, 2` has been put.

Comment: Well that's a change in your requirements from your initial statement at the top. Without knowing more about the jobs themselves which are queued, it sounds like you're really looking for something like Celery as a task executor and you modify the task parameters. If there's a resource restriction (hence why you're modifying execution order), going to distributed workers on separate machines sounds like a better move to remove the priority component and have all the jobs talk to a caching layer to enforce idempotency.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated this explicitly. For me the two initial requirements implied this behavior. But you are right, technically they don't. Sorry. Yes, your architectural solution avoids manual implementation of such a low-level thing as this queue. But for my purpose it works fine, and it does not feel like I produced too much technical debt by writing/using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the good:

- Ohh recent Python 3, nice!
- Good documentation
- Good use of `typing`. This is great for datastructures.
- Good formatting of your code. Nice spacing. Decent naming
- Good use of `defaultdict`
- Good use of `assert`s

Things I noticed along the way:

- `contains` is usually spelled `__contains__`. This way you can do `item in queue`.
- I'd rename `contains_with_prio`. I'm not sure if I would call it `contains`, but `queue.contains(item, priority=5)` reads better to me. At the least, don't abbreviate `priority`.
- I'd name `condition_var` to just `lock`. `with self.lock` reads better this way.
- If you name it `remove` for parity with how [the builtin `set` does it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), I'd have it `raise KeyError` if `item` isn't in the queue instead of returning a `bool`. If you want to return a `bool`, then name it `discard` (also for parity).
- I'd do `assert removed_count in (0, 1)` (tuples are preferred when you don't need to modify the object)
- Instead of `empty` define a `__bool__` which returns `True` if the queue has items. This is for parity with lists. lists and other builtins are falsy when empty
- Rename `size` to `__len__` so you can do `len(queue)`
- Rename `get` to `pop` (you even call it this in the comment) for parity with sets (and python's [heap implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html))
- For imports, I generally prefer `from unittest import TestCase`. Repeating the module name tends to be tedious and in many cases doesn't add much.
- Make sure your tests are in a separate file (if the source is in `foo/ordered_set_priority_queue.py` you'd typically place them in `test/foo/test_ordered_set_priority_queue.py`; this allows you--assuming you've added all the `__init__.py`s--to do `python3 -m unittest discover .` to run all tests)
- `queue.put(0, 1)` is unclear without looking at the method definition. Perhaps use a kwarg here to make it clearer: `queue.put(0, priority=1)`
- Using `Thread` in a test is fairly fragile. Generally, testing concurrent datastructures is tricky business. This test may not always fail if there is a problem in your code unless you're very careful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995491/testing-concurrent-data-structures. You're probably better off introducing some special breakpoints in your code (removed out for production) that allows you to pause your datastructure so you can specifically craft degenerate access patterns.
- One of the key parts of a priority queue is constant time access to the top of the queue. You actually don't have that because in your `get` you do `sorted(self.deques.keys())[-1]`. This is `n log n` and also inefficient because it sorts the whole list (when you only need the first element). It also requires building a list in memory. Consider using [python heaps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to maintain a sorted heap of priorities. This way your `get` is always constant time.
- Generally we prefix private attributes with `_`, so `self._deques`, `self._elem_sets` (call this `self._item_sets`, don't abbreviate), `self._lock`, etc.
- There's no need to do `priorities = list(self.elem_sets.keys())` in `_clean_up()`
- I'd benchmark to see if `_clean_up` is necessary. It may not be, and eliminating it makes the logic simpler (if you take my advice and use python heap stuff)
- For parity with Python sets rename `put` to `insert`

Here's a big detail:

The fact that you `assert sorted(self.deques.keys()) == sorted(self.elem_sets.keys())` is an indication that you have a data dependency that could probably be refactored. Ideally, you'd never want that to be `False`, but if you separately manage `deques` and `elem_sets` then perhaps they could get out of sync. This also gives you multiple ways to get all of the priority levels (ex. `self._deques.keys()` and `self._item_sets.keys()`). You can fix this be grouping a deque and set together into a `PriorityLevel`.

```
class PriorityLevel(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._ordered_items: Deque[T] = deque()
        self._items_set: Set[T] = {}

    def __contains__(self, item: T) -> bool:
        return item in self._items_set

    def pop(self) -> T:
        item = self._ordered_items.pop()
        self._items_set.remove(item)
        return item

    # etc.
```

Then have your datastructure maintain one `defaultdict` of these:

```
class OrderedSetPriorityQueue(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._levels: DefaultDict[int, PriorityLevel[T]] = defaultdict(PriorityLevel)

    def __contains__(self, item: T) -> bool:
        with self._lock:
             return any(item in level for level in self._levels.values())

    def insert(self, item, *, priority: int = 0) -> bool:
        with self._lock:
            self.discard(item)
            return self._levels[priority].insert(item)

    def discard(self, item: T) -> bool:
        with self._lock:
            return any(level.discard(item) for level in self._levels.values())

    # etc.
```

In this way you never have to have a `priority` and then hope that `self.deques[priority]` and `self.elem_sets[priority]` gives you what you want (and they haven't gotten out of sync).

You may also want to consider not using a global lock. A readwrite lock may be more efficient (especially for non-mutating operations). Refactoring out `PriorityLevel` may also allow you to do per-level locking, which may be more efficient than global locking.

Also, don't check `if item in self` before doing a `discard` for example. It's just needless work. Do the `discard` and handle failure accordingly. Also be careful with how this interacts with locking (I see you needed a `notify`, which I suspect stems from this).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this awesome review!

I just already implemented the majority of your smaller suggestions: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/37705392b4aaa3a3539ba1a61efec6b6

Next I'll look into heaps and use a `PriorityLevel` class, mainly to avoid possible out-of-sync situations, but also to drop `_clean_up` and make `pop` `O(1)`. Also I'll check out the `readerwriterlock` library.

The reason why I do `priorities = list(self._elem_sets.keys())` instead of directly using `for priority in self._elem_sets.keys():` is `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. And true! That makes sense. Though, that's a good reason for removing all of that complexity unless you can benchmark to prove its needed. Simple algorithms usually perform better :)

Comment: Nice review. I'd add two little things: a link to  [PEP3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) since you almost name it, and the usage of `any` for the implementation of `__contains__`: `return any(item in elem_set for elem_set in self.elem_set.values())`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Indeed, both of these are excellent suggestions :)